# css max-width not working, br after max width

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

is there anyone to help me about this article please:
firstly i want to know why max-width does not work in the below code
and secondly i need the content in tooltip to be continue till max-width and then it goes to the next line
thanks alot

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    max-width:500px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">TooltiptextTooltiptextTooltiptextTooltiptextTooltiptext</span>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 styles on tooltip div

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: hello , thanks alot, your solution solves break problem, but i need the content inside tooltip to be continue till max width and then goes to the next line, by the code you mentioned , it will occur for width , not max-width

Comment: You have applied width and max-width in pixels both on tooltiptext..How will both work together ? if you set width to 120px, then how can it take max-width ?

Comment: if you mean it's wrong , tell me the correct form of it please. because i have checked the max-width alone, but i didn't get result. the main problem is that , the max-width does not work any situation at all!